# Is it safe to store pointers to bufferevents?

Tags: c, sockets, libevent

I am working on a daemon, in C using *libevent* library, which accepts TCP connections and creates bufferevent (socket) for each accepted connection as following

```
struct bufferevent *bev = bufferevent_socket_new(
            base, 
            sfd, 
            BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);
```

What I what to do is to store the created bufferevent (sockets) for later use, say, in a array `struct event_info myevents[MAX_EVENTS]`, where `event_info` is defined as

```
struct event_info
{
  bufferevent* bev;
  /* additional standard data fields */
};
```

Later, when I am done with the socket I remove the event from the event base and remove the event_info from the array.

So, is it safe to store a pointer to a newly created bufferevent (created by `bufferevent_socket_new`) in the array?

Comment: It should be safe until you call `bufferevent_free` on the `bufferevent`. Make sure that you do call it after you're done with it, too!

Comment: Sure, I do call `bufferevent_free` before I remove the pointer from the array.